# How to center this element

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div id="1" style="display:block">
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o1"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt1"></label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt2"></label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt3"></label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt4"></label>
</div>
</div>
```

At the moment, it appears to the left of the screen. Please have a look. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "this element"...

Comment: also, numeric id is invalid (EDIT: in HTML 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want to center the div with id='1', it needs a parent element
HTML

```
<div id='parent'>
  <div id="myDiv" style="display:block">
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="o1">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt1">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="o2">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt2">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="o3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt3">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="o4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt4">
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g8oLjnus/
learn more about flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 2):

Try adding some CSS code

```css
#mydiv{

text-align:center
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv">
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o1"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt1"></label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt2"></label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt3"></label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt4"></label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: downvoter, could you leave a comment? or you don't event know what to say?

Comment: It does not work[Luis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3750462/luis-gonz%c3%a1lez)

Comment: has you run the code snippet? the element appears centered, what are you trying to get?

Answer (score 1):

if you use one of the following you can use it to centre it 50% will put the start of text or input box. px means you have to aline manually. insert this into  or the css file under #mydiv. to do this change your id to mydiv or something else.

```css
left:50px;
left:50%
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the `id` to `myid`; and added a parent `div`

```
<div class="parent">    
<div id="myid" style="display:block">
    <div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o1"> <input type="text" class="form-   control" id="opt1"></label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o2"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt2"></label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o3"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt3"></label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
      <label><input type="radio" name="o4"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="opt4"></label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The `.parent` class must be:

```
.parent{position: relative;}
```

And the `#myid` must be

```
#myid{
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Hope is works :)